# how to choose server that can handle about 1 or 2 million visit of my website

Tags: windows, sql, hosting, web-hosting

I am building website using Angular and .net core, some modules will be written in python

I have searched on hosting specs and know the difference between them and I am comfortable for dedicated server to help me manage the website, database , etc myself

the factor that I can not decide about the number of user, I asked the marketing team and they said that the expected number of users per month are 1 to 2 million visit

how to choose server specs that suit this number without affecting the server performance ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, [the most relevant answer has been provided by Gerald Schneider in the comments](https://serverfault.com/questions/384686/can-you-help-me-with-my-capacity-planning). Benchmark your application on a realistic dataset with expected user behavior. Multiply by expected traffic, identify the bottlenecks across applications, extrapolate from your test system. Sizing a system really requires in-depth knowledge of all involved applications, how various factors affect their performance and how hardware scales.

But to put things into perspective: Two million visits a month sounds like a lot. Though when you break it down to relevant numbers, that's less than one visitor per second. Unless you expect a large number of page loads per visitor, your code is abysmally inefficient, your database is huge or your server applications are badly configured, any average modern bare metal server will do.